# Move small text to top of its line

Tags: vertical-alignment, fontsize

Is it possible to have small text moved to the top of a line?

E.g., when you have a block of text with standard font size, but use `\scriptsize` for one line. The gap between the row above and the small text increases. Is there a way to move the small text to the top of his own line and thus have this gab between the small text and the line below?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm afraid your write-up is not exactly as clear as you might think. Please be more specific, and please give an example (mobile-phone snapshot of a hand-drawn diagram is OK) what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! AboAmmar got the answer with a screenshot of what I wanted, so I'll keep it like that and will remember to be more specific next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option without low-level macros is using `\raisebox` to the difference between two high letters like `h`. A line break of course is not supported here.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\newlength\bigH
\settoheight\bigH{h}
\newlength\smlH
\settoheight\smlH{\scriptsize h}

Is it possible to have small text moved to the top of a row? Is it possible to have 
\raisebox{\dimexpr\bigH-\smlH}{\scriptsize have small text moved to the top} of a row? 
Is it possible to have small text moved to the top of a row?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very straight forward answer to what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`\heightof` and `\height` seem to come in handy here.

Example:

```
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\BBBAL}{B\raisebox{\heightof{B}-\height}{\scriptsize 3}AL}
```

And output:

[image]